# Pandas flatten a time-series dataframe on same activity but different timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm looking to flatten certain processes. Basically looking at duplicates that are right after each other. Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
d = {'time': [12-08-2020, 13-08-2020, 14-08-2020, 15-08-2020, 16-08-2020], 'state': [off, on, on, on, off]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Then I would use `time.shift()` to create the "time_end" column. Basically the next rows time. result:

```
         time state    time_end
0  12-08-2020   off  13-08-2020
1  13-08-2020    on  14-08-2020
2  14-08-2020    on  15-08-2020
3  15-08-2020    on  16-08-2020
4  16-08-2020   off         NaN
```

My question is now, how do I flatten it so that it becomes in actuality 3 lines like this:

```
         time state    time_end
0  12-08-2020   off  13-08-2020
1  13-08-2020    on  16-08-2020
4  16-08-2020   off         NaN
```

For my code I dont need repeat on's if they are followed by another on. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the grouping of consecutive same `state` by [`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) + [`.ne()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) + [`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html).

Then, for each group (of consecutive same `state`), we get the first entry of `time` and last entry of `time_end` using [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html), as follows:

```
df['state_group'] = df['state'].ne(df['state'].shift()).cumsum()

df_out = df.groupby('state_group').agg({'time': 'first', 'state': 'first', 'time_end': 'last'}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

         time state    time_end
0  12-08-2020   off  13-08-2020
1  13-08-2020    on  16-08-2020
2  16-08-2020   off        None
```

Just for information, the following interim dataframe is created with the grouping of consecutive same `state` after the first line of codes above.  We based on this grouping to aggregate the desired flattened result.

```
         time state    time_end  state_group
0  12-08-2020   off  13-08-2020            1
1  13-08-2020    on  14-08-2020            2
2  14-08-2020    on  15-08-2020            2
3  15-08-2020    on  16-08-2020            2
4  16-08-2020   off         NaN            3
```

Comment: @HenryEcker  My base df is the one that have `time_end` column created by using `df.time.shift(-1)

Comment: Ah that makes sense. You started at step 2 and I started at step 1 gotcha. :)

Comment: @HenryEcker  Right, because the creation of `time_end` column is before OP mentioned `my question is now...`.  So, regard this as base.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

We can filter the DataFrame based on where the current row's `state` value does not equal the next row's `state` value, then create the `time_end` column by shifting back the filtered `time` column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'time': ['12-08-2020', '13-08-2020', '14-08-2020', '15-08-2020',
             '16-08-2020'],
    'state': ['off', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'off']
})

new_df = df[df['state'].ne(df['state'].shift())].reset_index(drop=True)
new_df['time_end'] = new_df['time'].shift(-1)
```

- [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)
- [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html)
- [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

`new_df`:

```
         time state    time_end
0  12-08-2020   off  13-08-2020
1  13-08-2020    on  16-08-2020
2  16-08-2020   off         NaN
```